# Angular-ui modal directive

Tags: javascript, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

Towards the end of the documentation for [Angular UI modal directive](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal), it is written

`In addition the scope associated with modal's content is augmented with 2 methods: * $close(result) * $dismiss(reason) Those methods make it easy to close a modal window without a need to create a dedicated controller`

I see this is implemented in commit
http://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/8d153acb

Is there any example on how to use it. I too like to avoid writing a controller for the example given in the doc. [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/T3kd5fz59lC8AQwaPJXF?p=preview) . So, I am seeking a way to avoid creating `ModalInstanceCtrl` for simple functionalities (input through a form, displaying some data).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your modal form simply use:

```
<button ng-click="$close(result)">OK</button>
```